Is it possible to transfer FALCON keys from C to Python and vice versa?
I'm currently trying out the FALCON signature algorithm. I can easily generate keys, sign and verify signatures both in C and in Python. But I couldn't find an easy way how to transfer keys from C to Python or the other way around.
Does anyone know how to do it?
For reference:

I use the Python standard implementation (git), which you can easily use in the Python IDLE.
For C I use the Python implementation from round 1 of NIST (zip/ or download directly from Falcon website under Resources -> For Reference) as you can easily test it in the terminal.

The essence of the Problem lies in the fact that in C the public key and private key are stored differently than in Python. In Python the arrays h, f, g, F, G are just as is, while in C they are encoded (using falcon_encode_... functions) before written to files.
An idea to solve this would be to take the functions falcon_vrfy_set_public_key from falcon_vrfy.c and falcon_sign_set_private_key from falcon-sign.c and write them into a new file. If you alter these functions correctly you should be able to get functions that take in the encoded key files and return h or f,g,F and G. Like this you should be able to transfer keys from C to Python.
Getting keys from Python to C is a bit harder. I think I have an idea on how you should be able to do it, its similar to the above, but this time you do it like in the last few lines of falcon-keygen.c.
I don't doubt that it's possible, but before starting this exhausting work myself I just wanted to know if someone has already done this, so that I don't have to. Thanks! :)
Edit:
So, I dit exactly what I proposed: I was able to transfer a public key from C to python. Turns out that when I try to verify in Python the signature generated in C, it tells me it is not valid. Maybe you're not meant to transfer keys, as the Python and C algorithms differ? I could imagine that there is a difference in the way their shake256 algorithms hash the message. But perhaps I just made a mistake somewhere.

You should read the description of a tag before you use it. falcon quite clearly says it's about a "multi-paradigm programming language", not some signing algorithm.

So, I was able to do it just how I explained it. An important thing to not forget is that when you decode the public key (like in falcon_verify_set_public_key) you must not convert the h polynomial to NTT and Montgommery representation, meaning that you must not apply mq_NTT and mq_poly_tomonty to h.
However encoding the public key and encoding or decoding the private key are straightforward.
Is this something that more people need? I basically already coded C and Python scripts that are able to pass keys to one another and I'm thinking about doing this neatly and then uploading it, so that other people can use it.
If this is something you would be interested in, give this a thumbs up, text me or let me know in any way.
Edit:
Also converting signatures is straightforward. Keep in mind that Python signatures are always 1  byte information, 40 bytes nonce and the rest is the signature, while C signatures are 1 byte info then the signature and a separate nonce. C supports nonces of variable lengths, so if you want to have it compatible with Python you need to have it be 40 bytes. When you convert a signature from C to Python or vice versa, flip the 4th bit of the first byte, as this bit indicates whether it is a Python or a C signature and insert or extract the nonce after the first byte.

Instead of asking to leave thumbs up and message. You should provide the answer and in the begining of the answer just reply straight yes or no. after that you can explain.

I believe you didn't understand my answer. It is possible. You can transfer keys and signatures from C to Python and the other way around.
My question was whether I should clean and upload the code so that other people can use it. It's 700 lines of unorganized code so far, I can't just upload that here
